# Best way to integrate Vaadin 7 and EJB or how make service layer?

Tags: java, jpa, service, ejb, vaadin

what is the best way to integrate Vaadin 7 and EJB? Or how make service layer? I want use JPA to persist data. I'm thinking about this schema: Vaadin -> EJB(Service) -> JPA. Maybe you have better solution. By the way, in future I will add Web Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your architecture is simple (that's good), just let me suggest you some concepts that fits with your future intentions.

The way how you think the app could be something like:

UI -> boundary -> control -> entity

from the technology view, is something like:

Vaadin (MVC/P) -> EJB's -> CDI Objects -> JPA Entities.

The main advantages with this approach are :

Your UI could be anything you like (JSF, GWT, Vaadin...), and is not tied to the service layer.

The boundary express the contracts that offers your service layer, it is, you could reuse this boundary and give it any kind of exposure that you need, this would be a rest-boundary, webservice-boundary, rmi-boundary, so on, any kind of protocol that you need.

With the EJB as your boundary, you can initiate asynchronous methods, JMS consumers, enforces security at service layer and use the timer service.

The CDI controls will let you use dependency injection in fancy ways (did you know the configurator pattern? > http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_configure_java_ee) , and if you have a business problem that requires a kind of pattern (factory, template method, complex inheritance, producers ....) CDI lets you implements all of this in expressive ways. Without mention that EJB + CDI is a deal breaker!.

The Controls are orchestrated by the boundary and its behaviour should be well encapsulated. Obviously your boundary could use as many controls as necesary, but no over-engineering, if with just one boundary is enough, well, keep it simple.

Finally the JPA entities, try to express has much business concepts as possible, if you have an inheritance between relations, dont be afraid to implement it with JPA. This will save you boilerplate code, remove duplication across the system and easier to work with. (tip: try to use the bean validation spec.)

note: this is based in SOA concepts (i.e. @Stateless EJB's), if your app is more RIA oriented, could be useful for you learn how to use the @Stateful EJB's (Gateway Pattern)

Have fun!